# Typescript String Comparison Oddity with String.toLowerCase

Tags: javascript, typescript

while curious (and no JS background) I'm beginning to dive into Typescript and face a brick wall.
I want to compare two strings and to make life easy they will be aligned to lowercase first. This is the code:

```js
let bool: boolean = false;
let i = 0;
this.comparisons[++i] = " init bool " + " => " + bool;

bool = false;
if ("a" == "a") { bool = true };
this.comparisons[++i] = ' "a" == "a" ' + " => " + bool;

bool = false;
if ("a" == "b") { bool = true };
this.comparisons[++i] = ' "a" == "b" ' + " => " + bool;

bool = false;
if ("a" == "A") { bool = true };
this.comparisons[++i] = ' "a" == "A" ' + " => " + bool;

bool = false;
if ("a".toLowerCase == "A".toLowerCase) { bool = true };
this.comparisons[++i] = ' "a".toLowerCase == "A".toLowerCase ' + " => " + bool;

bool = false;
if ("a".toLowerCase == "B".toLowerCase) { bool = true };
this.comparisons[++i] = ' "a".toLowerCase == "B".toLowerCase ' + " => " + bool;
```

and it prints:

```
init bool => false

"a" == "a" => true

"a" == "b" => false

"a" == "A" => false

"a".toLowerCase == "A".toLowerCase => true

"a".toLowerCase == "B".toLowerCase => true
```

Why does the last expression evaluate to true?

"a" == "b" should evaluate to false like the third statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a method you must use the parentheses `()`, even when there are no arguments to pass to the method:

```
bool = false;
if ("a".toLowerCase() == "B".toLowerCase()) { bool = true };
```

Or simply:

```
bool = ("a".toLowerCase() == "B".toLowerCase());
```

Without the parentheses, `"a".toLowerCase` is simply a reference to the `String.toLowerCase` method itself. The result of the comparison is `true` because it compares the two methods and finds that they are indeed the same method.

Comment: Another hint for future readers: If you're coding in Visual Studio Code pay attention to the auto completion as it will **not** add the required `()` as of 2016-04-20 Version 1.0.0